# Paypal Sandbox, how to verify sale with IPN for specific cart ID

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I want to setup paypal sandbox to test sales. what i have done so far is setup seller and buyer account, created form for sanbox, enabled IPN.

What i dont understand is how i know which sale is being processed.
The IPN only send:
 buyers desription
 item purchased
 paid amount.

I want to know, how can i send a cart id to sandbox, and receive it back with IPN, so i can process it.

i didn't found anyinformation about this on google and paypal documents.
Please help me on this, it took me many days and i haven't figured how to verify sales.

Comment: Is this for Website payments Basic?

Comment: yes, i basically want to verify sales based on some cart id or key for current user, so i can make sale based on paypal ipn result,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a variable you can pass in your HTML form called ***custom*** ([variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)). This field will be passed back to you in your IPN ([IPN Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)). You can populate this with up to 255 characters and the customer won't see any of it.

Comment: hi, thanks 4 reply, i'll check and try ur suggestion, but i am out of town, will check after a while & reply back. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `invoice` (which you should have to pass to paypal) or pass your own id through `custom`

edit: note that invoice must be unique, you cannot resuse an invoice to paypal otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: hi, thanks 4 reply, i will look into custom fields, and try out. i'm out of town, will chk and reply back. thanks

Comment: One caveat on using invoice vs custom is that custom supports 256 characters while invoice only supports 127